# I want to build android app using eclipse.but getting these errors, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, api, sdk, eclipse-plugin

```
the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!
 failed to collect preference classes
```

These are the errors running android in eclipse.

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. why are you still making use of eclipse ?

Comment: You should use Android Studio for Android development, if you are using eclipse because you saw it in a tutorial then I guess you should also look for a more updated tutorial :)

Comment: Thank you for your response.i used android Studio, but it not work perfect .because i have only 4gb ram PC it is not insufficient for android development software.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for several years now, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help with any problems you have with it.

Comment: oops i don't know about that.I m the new comer to learn it.Thank You.